# jquery error same value get radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('input[name=vehicle]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#carcost').show();
    var vn = $('input[name=vehicle]:radio').val();
    var pp = $('#ppriceh').val();
    alert(vn);
    if (vn == 'sedan') {
      var px = pp;
    } else if (vn == 'suv') {
      var px = pp + 20;
    } else {
      var px = pp * 3;
    }
    $('#carcost span').text(px);

  } else {
    $('#carcost').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="vehicleItem">
  <label>
    <div class="contur ">
      <input type="radio" name="vehicle" id="vehicle0" class="vehicleRadio inpColor c_blue" value="sedan"> <strong>sedan</strong>

      <div id="pricev" class="vehiclePrice suvprice">$177
        <input type="hidden" id="ppriceh" name="vrate" value="59.00" />
      </div>
      <div class="vehicleImage">
        <img src="http://server14.testingserver.ca/bestairportlimo/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/vehicle_mkt8.jpg" width="100" height="80" border="0">
      </div>
      <div class="vehiclePax">4</div>
      <div class="vehicleLugg">2</div>

    </div>
  </label>
</div>


<div class="vehicleItem">
  <label>
    <div class="contur ">
      <input type="radio" name="vehicle" id="vehicle0" class="vehicleRadio inpColor c_blue" value="suv"> <strong>suv</strong>

      <div id="pricev" class="vehiclePrice suvprice">$177
        <input type="hidden" id="ppriceh" name="vrate" value="59.00" />
      </div>
      <div class="vehicleImage">
        <img src="http://server14.testingserver.ca/bestairportlimo/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/vehicle_suv3.jpg" width="100" height="80" border="0">
      </div>
      <div class="vehiclePax">6</div>
      <div class="vehicleLugg">3</div>

    </div>
  </label>
</div>


<div class="vehicleItem">
  <label>
    <div class="contur ">
      <input type="radio" name="vehicle" id="vehicle0" class="vehicleRadio inpColor c_blue" value="van"> <strong>van</strong>

      <div id="pricev" class="vehiclePrice suvprice">$177
        <input type="hidden" id="ppriceh" name="vrate" value="59.00" />
      </div>
      <div class="vehicleImage">
        <img src="http://server14.testingserver.ca/bestairportlimo/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/vehicle_van1.jpg" width="100" height="80" border="0">
      </div>
      <div class="vehiclePax">10</div>
      <div class="vehicleLugg">5</div>

    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

always show only sedan when radio button select suv show sedan same van show sedan  why these show same value... i am getting all car value in html using database..

alert show  value sedan..

please help ,me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find teh hidden input value, relative to the checked checkbox

```js
$('input[name=vehicle]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#carcost').show();
    var vn = this.value;
    //convert the value to numeric
    var pp = +$(this).closest('.vehicleItem').find('input[name="vrate"]').val() || 0;

    snippet.log(vn + ':' + pp)

    if (vn == 'sedan') {
      var px = pp;
    } else if (vn == 'suv') {
      var px = pp + 20;
    } else {
      var px = pp * 3;
    }
    $('#carcost span').text(px);

  } else {
    $('#carcost').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carcost">Cost: <span></span>
</div>
<div class="vehicleItem">
  <label>
    <div class="contur ">
      <input type="radio" name="vehicle" id="vehicle0" class="vehicleRadio inpColor c_blue" value="sedan" /> <strong>sedan</strong>

      <div id="pricev" class="vehiclePrice suvprice">$180
        <input type="hidden" id="ppriceh" name="vrate" value="180.00" />
      </div>
      <div class="vehicleImage">
        <img src="http://server14.testingserver.ca/bestairportlimo/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/vehicle_mkt8.jpg" width="100" height="80" border="0">
      </div>
      <div class="vehiclePax">4</div>
      <div class="vehicleLugg">2</div>

    </div>
  </label>
</div>


<div class="vehicleItem">
  <label>
    <div class="contur ">
      <input type="radio" name="vehicle" id="vehicle0" class="vehicleRadio inpColor c_blue" value="suv"> <strong>suv</strong>

      <div id="pricev" class="vehiclePrice suvprice">$177
        <input type="hidden" id="ppriceh" name="vrate" value="177.00" />
      </div>
      <div class="vehicleImage">
        <img src="http://server14.testingserver.ca/bestairportlimo/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/vehicle_suv3.jpg" width="100" height="80" border="0">
      </div>
      <div class="vehiclePax">6</div>
      <div class="vehicleLugg">3</div>

    </div>
  </label>
</div>


<div class="vehicleItem">
  <label>
    <div class="contur ">
      <input type="radio" name="vehicle" id="vehicle0" class="vehicleRadio inpColor c_blue" value="van"> <strong>van</strong>

      <div id="pricev" class="vehiclePrice suvprice">$177
        <input type="hidden" id="ppriceh" name="vrate" value="177.00" />
      </div>
      <div class="vehicleImage">
        <img src="http://server14.testingserver.ca/bestairportlimo/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/vehicle_van1.jpg" width="100" height="80" border="0">
      </div>
      <div class="vehiclePax">10</div>
      <div class="vehicleLugg">5</div>

    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: sir one more help need here i want to add 59+ 20= 79 not 59.0029 please help me.. thanks

Comment: declare to js that is it a number not string so it will add and not concat. you can use parseInt()

Comment: @avktech have you tried `var pp = +$(this).closest('.vehicleItem').find('input[name="vrate"]').val() || 0;`

Comment: `var car =$('#carcost span').val(px);
    var meetr=$('#meetrate span').val();
    var bsitr=$('#bayrate span').val();
    var tot = car + meetr + bsitr .val()|| 0;
     $('#totrate span').text(tot);
     $('#totrate').show();`

Comment: `var car = +$('#carcost span').val(px) || 0; ` and `var meetr= +$('#meetrate span').val(); || 0` do the same for other numeric fields like `bsitr` also

Comment: sir above jquery code i want to get some value from like  `<div id="meetrate"> <?php value from databse  ?></div>` how to get total like three value in jquery..

Comment: sir last one ... please help me   how to get total all above variable like `var car var meetr`  also check `var tot = car + meetr + bsitr ;`